# Holding onto a struct

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, struct

How can I hang onto the following struct outside of the method it is created? I've been trying to assign it to a instance variable or property without much luck.

```
@property(nonatomic) CTParagraphStyleSetting defaultParagraphSettings;

- (void)someMethod {
    CTParagraphStyleSetting settings[] = {
        { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(CTTextAlignment), &alignment },
        { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineBreakMode, sizeof(CTLineBreakMode), &lineBreakMode },
    };
    self.defaultParagraphSettings = settings;
}
```

`self.defaultParagraphSettings = settings;` generates the following error:

```
Assigning to 'CTParagraphStyleSetting' (aka 'struct CTParagraphStyleSetting') from incompatible type 'CTParagraphStyleSetting [4]'
```

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: One issue: you want `defaultParagraphSettings` to be of type `CTParagraphStyleSetting *`, not `CTParagraphStyleSetting`.

Comment: That's even worse - it would assign the pointer to stack memory that would instantly go out of scope and its contents would therefore be undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the variable `settings` is of type *array* of `CTParagraphStyleSetting`, the property `defaultParagraphSettings` is of type  `CTParagraphStyleSetting`. So you have two problems, (1) the types are incompatible and (2) (Objective-)C does not support array assignment.

I can't tell you how to fix it as that depends on what you're trying to do. But for example, the statement:

```
self.defaultParagraphSettings = settings[0];
```

should assign the first element of the array to the property.

Comment: Thanks CRD. that is helpful. What I am trying to do is to hang onto the entire contents of settings, rather than just the first element. This way I can reuse it later to create a CTParagraphStyleRef.

Comment: However I am starting to think that sticking the settings into a method that returns a struct/array is probably easier. - The goal being to avoid duplicate code.

Comment: @Matt - You have a 3 field struct, just create when needed - holding onto them for re-use is more trouble than it is worth. If you really want a "collection" of these one option is instead of having an array which you must index write a method that takes the "index", does a `switch`, and returns the "element".